# style attribute is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, styles

```js
const cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

for(const card of cards){
    card.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

the style property is not working correctly. It was working two line before now it's not working. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Provide a [mcve] (where's the HTML this is supposed to operate on? Use the stack snippets feature of the question editor to provide a live demo!). [Not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem.

Comment: @MisterJojo — Nonsense. `getElementsByClassName` is entirely reliable. (And ES6 doesn't have any DOM features anyway).

Answer (score -1):

You have to give some height or padding on the cards. Then it will be shown.

```
for (const card of cards) {
  card.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  card.style.padding= '20px'
}
```